# Using Impala to select multiple tables with wildcard pattern and concatenate them

Tags: python, sql, hadoop, impala

I'm starting with `Impala SQL` and `Hadoop` and have a (probably simple) question.

I have a `Hadoop` database with hundrets of tables with the same schema and naming convention (e.g. *process_1*, *process_2*, *process_3* and so on). How would I query all the tables and concatenate them into one big table or dataframe? Is it possible to do so by using just `Impala` SQL which returns one dataframe in `python`?

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 'process_*';
```

Or do I need to run `SHOW TABLES 'process_*'`, use a loop in python and query each table seperately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking purely Impala solution, then one approach would be to create a view on top of all of the tables. Something as below:

```
create view process_view_all_tables as
 select * from process1
 union all
 select * from process2
 union all
 ...
 select * from processN;
```

The **disadvantage** with this approach is as below:

- You need to union multiple tables together. Union is an expensive operation in terms of memory utilisation. Works ok if you have less number of tables say in range of 2-5 tables.
- You need to add all the tables manually. If you a new process table in future, you would need to ALTER the view and then add the new table. This is a maintenance headache.
- The view assumes that all the PROCESS tables are of the same schema.

In the **Second approach**, as you said, you could query the list of tables from Impala using `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'process*'` and write a small program to iterate over the list of tables and create the files.
Once you have the file generated, you could port the file back to HDFS and create a table on top of it.

The only disadvantage with the second approach is that for every iteration there would impala database requests which is particularly disadvantageous in a multi-tenant database env.

In my opinion, you should try the second approach.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: OK, I was hoping to find in Impala something like in Google's BigQuery where you could just use wildcards in the FROM statement (see also here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables). Nevertheless I tried the second python-based approach and it works totally fine. I guess I just have to live with it :-)